# Attempt to create group in Active Directory under OU using ldapadd tool responds with "NAMING_VIOLATION" error

Tags: active-directory, ldap

File content:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmpmynxzg3sldap_group
dn: cn=group-1760882938,ou=Employees,dc=<some>,dc=<dc>
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixGroup
gidNumber: 1760882938
memberUid: user-e9ca0681
```

ldapadd command error:

```
    $ ldapadd -H ldap://<AD URL> -x -w <pass> -D CN=<Bind DN> -f /tmp/tmpmynxzg3sldap_group
ldap_add: Naming violation (64)
        additional info: 00002099: NameErr: DSID-0305126E, problem 2005 (NAMING_VIOLATION), data 0, best match of:
        'ou=Employees,dc=<some>,dc=<dc>'
```

Any advices how to debug/solve it are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it but I'd recommend to add the following line to your LDIF snippet:

```
cn: group-1760882938
```